# I got an 'Reference Error: button is not defined' error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Currently learning 'What is Closure' and try this practice code. Running in **Visual studio code**.

```
for (let [idx,btn] of buttons.entries()) { 
    btn.addEventListener(
        "click",
        function onClick(){ 
            console.log(
                `Clicked on button (${ idx })!
                `); 
            }
        ); 
     }
```

Expected to have each iteration gets new block-scoped (idx,btn) variables; and expected the loop also creates a new inner onClick(..) function each time.But it got this error.

```
PS C:\Users\leePC\babel\public\src> node test.js
C:\Users\leePC\babel\public\src\test.js:1
for (let [idx,btn] of buttons.entries()) { 
btn.addEventListener("click",function onClick(){ 
console.log(`Clicked on button (${ idx })!`); }); }
                          ^

ReferenceError: buttons is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> 
(C:\Users\leePC\babel\public\src\test.js:1:31)
    at Module._compile 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1177:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:32)
    at Function.Module._load 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:900:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] 
(internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
```

Since some people said I should implement

```
npm install react-uikit-button --save;

// ES6
import Button from 'react-uikit-button';

// ES5
var Button = require('react-uikit-button');
```

And try import in the front of code, but it still does not work. It pops up different error...
How to fix this?

edit: when I use import statement and then converted this code by Babel, this error is happened.(in Visual studio code)

`'Button' is declared but its value is never read`

Comment: `never read` means you didn't use the Button anywhere in your code yet

Comment: *ReferenceError: buttons is not defined* So, where did you define `buttons`? (sounds like you didn't)

Comment: Oh I am stupid..thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
//May be the scope of buttons does not exists.
//Try to run this one.
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(`[id]`)

                for (let [idx, btn] of buttons.entries()) {
                    btn.addEventListener("click", function onClick() {
                        alert(`Clicked on button (${idx})!
                `);
                    });
                }

            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="myFunction()">
        <button id="0"> 0 </button>
        <button id="1"> 1 </button>
        <button id="2"> 2 </button>
        <button id="3"> 3 </button>
        <button id="4"> 4 </button>
    </body>

</html>
```